# Unable to generate URL for named route

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to generate link to URL which contains two parameters (both of those parameters are not really necessary but I do it for practice). I created custom `showAction` in `DiscovererController`

```
   /**
    *   @Route("/rivers/{river_id}/discoverers/{id}", name="discoverer_show")
    *   @Template
    */

    public function showAction($river_id, $id){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $river = $em->getRepository('MyOwnBundle:River')->find($river_id);

        if(!$river){
            throw $this->createNotFoundException("no river with provided id");
        }   

        $entity = $river->getDiscoverer();

        return array('entity' => $entity);
    }
```

As you can see two parameters are passed, id of the river and id of the discoverer (which is absurd but as I said, practice...).
In show action of a river (/rivers/1) I decided to put following code:

```
<a href="{{ path('discoverer_show', {'river_id': entity.id, 'id': entity.discoverer.id})}}"><p>{{entity.discoverer.name}}</p></a>
```

Note that 'entity' is a river here, and river has a discoverer. Unfortunatelly, when I try to render this action, I get error which tells me that:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "discoverer_show" as such route does not exist.") in /path/to/project/src/My/OwnBundle/Resources/views/River/show.html.twig at line 9.
```

I dont have a clue what is wrong, I provided both necessary parameters and used "discoverer_show" which I defined in my controller. How to correctly render this link?

Answer (score 1):

A piece of advice: **do not use tabs** in your source code at all! Make your IDE to replace tab character with 4 spaces. This could save you a lot of trouble... Tabs does not behave well in git too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, by accident i figured it out. Turns out annotations in symfony2 CANNOT begin with tab.

So this thing right here is NOT going to work

```
/**
*   @Route("/people")
*/
```

But this will work like a charm:

```
/**
* @Route("/people")
*/
```